# AirDrop simulator

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, airdrop

I want to build an AirDrop simulator that can communication with the real apple device, but I get some difficulty on it.

In the Apple device, if it can recognize other device open the AirDrop function(Wi-Fi and bluetooth), then it will pop up a icon and you can select it.

But there will be a question, the first step of AirDrop to build a recognition is using Bluetooth Low energy to advertising, I don't know what information contained in that frame. I also found that normal bluetooth adapter most likely cannot perform sniffing the BLE frame, generate and send it. Is it any method can deal with it or I need to have some specific device to perform this step? I want to perform the recognition step first.